# Make video preview thumbnail with ffmpeg

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I am trying to make a video preview of a movie using ffmpeg.

I want the preview video to be:

- a mp4 file
- be resized to 320 in width with correct (and even) aspect ratio
- last 5 seconds
- have 3 frames per second, for a total of 15 frames

So, with ffprobe, I calculate X so that:

```
X = source duration * source fps / (3 frames * 5 seconds)
```

then I do:

```
ffmpeg -hide_banner -ss 5 -i d:\test.mp4 -y
-vf "select='not(mod(n, {X defined above}))',setpts=N/3/TB,scale=320:-2"
-an -vcodec libx264 -t 5 -r 3 output.mp4
```

to speed things up, I'd also like to use *-skip_frame nokey* since I'm not really attached to frames being at an exact interval.

I also tried to use *-vf thumbnail={X},setpts=N/TB* as a filter but, in both cases, I don't get the expected result.

A command line like:

```
ffmpeg -hide_banner -ss 5 -i test.mp4 -y -vf thumbnail=1541,setpts=N/TB -r 1 -vcodec libx264 -vframes 15 -r 3 output.mp4
```

creates a file with a single frame for 154 seconds (1541 being the value {X} defined above, for this test movie), so there is something I don't understand right. Even if it worked, it wouldn't let met use the closest keyframe either since the *skip_frame nokey* option doesn't help anything here.
ffplay will play 6 frames, vlc just show one...

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: *length * {X defined above}* --> why is the length factor present here?

Comment: sorry, it should just read {X defined above}, I started to type the definition of X, and made a mistake; I'll fix the main post.

Comment: Ok, need to see full log. Add -report and run first command. Share the report.

Comment: Here is the log: http://pastebin.com/Vxpws210    I abridged the parts that repeat a lot to fit within pastebin's 512kb limit.

Comment: Umm, `n` is frame index, which is an integer, unlike timestamp, so the modulus will return a non-zero value when divided by such a floating point value. Either pass an integer value from the outset, or truncate it within ffmpeg: `not(mod(n, trunc(X)))`

Comment: When I remove the decimal part, the video works perfectly in ffplay, but VLC and browser stay stuck on frame 1. Do I need to specify anything else to make it work?

Comment: Try increasing r to 15. Don't change anything else.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138256/discussion-between-thomas-and-mulvya).

Comment: X has to be an integer!! Let's continue here.